# How to change iteratively the values of a column in R without a loop?

Tags: r, purrr, accumulate

I would like to change iteratively the values of a column (value2 in the example). value2 at time i is conditioned by value1 and updated value2 at time i and i-1.

Time values are stocked in ascending order.

Treatment is done separetely for each value of the group colum.

But as describe on my example, I can't succeed to update value2 with accumulate2 (purrr package).

Maybe someone could give me some advices to do this.

Thank you.

```
input <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                value1=c(4,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                value2=c(4,2,1,3,3,1,1))

input<-arrange(input, group,time)

my_function <- function(df) {
df %>%
as_tibble() %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(value2=purrr::accumulate2(.x = value2, .y = ((value1==lag(value1))
                                              & (lag(value2)==value1)
                                              & (value1!=value2))[-1],
                               .f = function(.i_1, .i, .y) {
                                 if (.y) {.i_1} else {.i}  
                               }) %>% unlist())
}

> input
  group time value1 value2
1     1    1      4      4
2     1    2      2      2
3     1    3      2      1
4     2    1      3      3
5     2    2      3      3
6     2    3      3      1
7     2    4      3      1

output <- my_function(input)

> output
  group time value1 value2
1     1     1      4      4
2     1     2      2      2
3     1     3      2      2 -> data change (OK)
4     2     1      3      3
5     2     2      3      3
6     2     3      3      3 -> data change (OK)
7     2     4      3      1 -> no data change / should be replaced by 3
```

Comment: use a `for`-loop. Make it work first.

Comment: thanks Mossa but my real dataframe contains 800.000 lines and a treatment including loop is too long. @Dan Chaltiel

Comment: We can help with making it vectorised, but I've got no idea what the actual problem is. I propose you make it work with a small example, and then ask for it to be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem lies in your algorithm. Unfortunately, as you didn't explain it here, we cannot help you in that matter.

`purrr::accumulate2` can be hard to use, so I advise you to split your code as much as possible. This will make your code much more readable, and will make debugging and finding errors much easier.

For instance, consider this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
input <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                    time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                    value1=c(4,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                    value2=c(4,2,1,3,3,1,1))
input <- arrange(input, group,time)

#document your functions when it
#' @param .i_1 this is ...
#' @param .i this is ...
#' @param .y this is ...
my_accu_function = function(.i_1, .i, .y) {
    if(.y) {.i_1} else {.i}  
}

my_function <- function(df) {
    df %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        group_by(group) %>%
        mutate(
            cond = value1==lag(value1) & 
              lag(value2)==value1 & 
              value1!=value2,
            value2_update=purrr::accumulate2(.x = value2, 
                                             .y = cond[-1],
                                             .f = my_accu_function) %>% unlist()
        )
}


input
#>   group time value1 value2
#> 1     1    1      4      4
#> 2     1    2      2      2
#> 3     1    3      2      1
#> 4     2    1      3      3
#> 5     2    2      3      3
#> 6     2    3      3      1
#> 7     2    4      3      1
output = my_function(input)
output
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group  time value1 value2 cond  value2_update
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>         <dbl>
#> 1     1     1      4      4 FALSE             4
#> 2     1     2      2      2 FALSE             2
#> 3     1     3      2      1 TRUE              2
#> 4     2     1      3      3 FALSE             3
#> 5     2     2      3      3 FALSE             3
#> 6     2     3      3      1 TRUE              3
#> 7     2     4      3      1 FALSE             1
stopifnot(output$value2_update[7]==3)
#> Error: output$value2_update[7] == 3 is not TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can see that `cond` is FALSE in the end, so `accumulate2` did its job putting the current value `1` and not the previous value `3`.

If you explain your algorithm to us, maybe we can help you with setting the proper condition `cond` so that you get the right output.